# echo each result of a for i in range

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need the permissions of a group of files on some servers, so I've got to connect to each server and retrieve this file names and chmods

in order to do this, I've got this planned

```
for i in $SERVERS
      do
         PERM=$(ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -2qC user@$i stat "/some/path/*.file" -c %A,%n) 
done
```

but then I tried (without success) to echo the results into a file

```
echo "$SERVERS,$PERM" >> statistics.csv
```

how can I print out every case of $PERM with the respective server, take into consideration every server is different and there can be more than 1 file on /some/path/*.file ?

I also tried inside the loop, echoing `echo "$i,$PERM" >> statistics.csv` no luck whatsoever

Comment: What does _no luck_ mean?

Answer (score 2):

Echo also have to be in loop

```
for i in $SERVERS; do
    PERM=$(ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -2qC user@$i stat "/some/path/*.file" -c %A,%n)
    echo "$i,$PERM" >> statistics.csv
done
```